# Pulling remote branch without checkout (from another branch)

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I am participating in a project with many branches and when I work on my branch, another branch (for example `master`) gets updated on remote. I indeed would like to pull changes to it without changing my current branch (without checking out). Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`git fetch <remote> <source>:<destination>` . 
 
[This](https://github.com/schuyler1d/git-forward-merge) worked for me `git-forward-merge <source> <destination>` But it doesn't work for merges that require conflict resolution.

Answer (score 1):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```